# How to retreive data from Json using java

Tags: java, json

hi guys i have json response like this

```
  Response response = service.execute(requestSendToNS);
       // JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        //String data = jsonResponse.getString("id");
        System.out.println("Response Body : " + response.getBody());
```

and here the result :

```
Response Body : [{"status":"success","message":"update success","id":"1404","internalid":2604},{"status":"failed","message":"bad location is already used in another location","id":1405}]
```

my question is how to getting value "id" from my json response ?

i have try use this code :

```
// JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        //String data = jsonResponse.getString("id");
```

i also have use this
List responseObject = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(),List);

but i cannot mapping from json Array to object

but i cannot retreive value from id

Comment: You can use json serializer/deserializer library like Gson or ObjectMapper

Comment: You can use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`, it has a method `readValue` which will take `final String json, Class<T> type` and will return `<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your response body is an array.

```
[{...},{...}]
```

That's why you can't get id

```
String data = jsonResponse.getString("id");
```

Please have a look JsonReader to read json as JsonArray

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonReader.html#readObject--

```
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response.getBody()));
JsonArray array = jsonReader.readArray();
JsonObject obj = array.getJsonObject(0);
String data = obj.getString("id");
```

Comment: i cannot find Json.createReader on java 11... how to read it on java 11 because i need to change the reference name @Huy Nguyen

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonReader.html, java11 also support java 7 ... so i guess code still work with higher java version

Comment: but when i check on my intellij i got error red line....

Comment: you can take a look about jackson api or gson api, those library support json very well ... in case you can't use JsonReader ...

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a class that has the exact same structure as the `JSON` response, and then you can use `ObjectMapper` from `jackson` library to write the `JSON` to class and read the values from it.